# outer selectAll: what is selected?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am learning D3, and how to nest or append elements to the page using D3's data binding mechanism.

I have modified code found on http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/ . I understand how to set up the svg canvas and I also understand the loops binding data to the rect, text and line elements.

What I don't understand are the calls to `selectAll('Anything1/2/3/4')` below. They are clearly necessary, but what exactly am I selecting, and how do they fit in the data binding mechanism? Thank you.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

var dat = [ { title:"A", subtitle:"a", year: 2006, books: 54, avg:10 },
            { title:"B", subtitle:"b", year: 2007, books: 43, avg:10 },
            { title:"C", subtitle:"c", year: 2008, books: 41, avg:10 },
            { title:"D", subtitle:"d", year: 2009, books: 44, avg:10 },
            { title:"E", subtitle:"e", year: 2010, books: 35, avg:10 } ];

var width    = 560,
    height   = 500,
    margin   = 20,
    innerBarWidth =  20,
    outerBarWidth =  40;


var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dat.length]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, height - 2 * margin])
    .domain([ 0 , 100 ]);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var n = d3.format(",d"),
    p = d3.format("%");

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 2 * margin + "," + margin + ")");

// outerbars
var outerBars = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("Anything1").data(dat).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(datum, index) { return x(index); })
  .attr("y", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.books); })
  .attr("height", function(datum) { return y(datum.books); })
  .attr("width", outerBarWidth)
  .attr("fill", "blue")

// innerbars
var innterBars = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("Anything2").data(dat).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(datum, index) { return x(index)+innerBarWidth/2; })
  .attr("y", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.books)/2; })
  .attr("height", function(datum) { return y(datum.books); })
  .attr("width", innerBarWidth)
  .attr("fill", "red");

// avg references
var barlabels = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("Anything3").data(dat).enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(datum, index) { return x(index); })
  .attr("x2", function(datum, index) { return x(index)+outerBarWidth; })
  .attr("y1", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.books)/2; })
  .attr("y2", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.books)/2; })
  .style("stroke", "#ccc");

// titles
var barlabels = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("Anything4").data(dat).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(datum, index) { return x(index)+innerBarWidth/2; })
  .attr("y", height )
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function (d) {return d.title} );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the most important, yet most difficult concept to understand in d3 is the [selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) (I highly recommend you bookmark and familiarize yourself with the API). On the surface, selections provide similar functionality to many other JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery:

jQuery:

```
var paragraphs = $("p");
```

d3:

```
var paragraphs = d3.selectAll("p");
```

Both these lines create "selection objects", which are essentially DOM elements which have been grouped into a single object which gives you better control over the elements. Like other libraries, you can manipulate these "selected" elements in d3 using functions that are provided in the library.

jQuery:

```
var paragraphs = $("p").css("color", "red");
```

d3:

```
var paragraphs = d3.selectAll("p").style("color", "red");
```

Again, on the surface this is fairly easy to understand. What makes d3 so powerful is that it lets you take this a step further by [allowing you to bind arbitrary data to the selected elements.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)

Let's say you have a blank document and you want to add a couple paragraphs of text - and you have each paragraph of text stored in individual elements in an array:

```
var text = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];
```

Since we haven't yet created these paragraphs, the following call will return an [empty selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-empty):

```
var paragraphs = d3.selectAll("p");
console.log(paragraphs.empty()); // true
```

Note that `paragraphs` is still a selection, it is just empty. This is a fundamental point in d3. You can bind data to an empty selection, and then use the data to add new elements using the [entering selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter). Let's start over from our previous example and walk through this process. First, create your empty selection and bind the `text` array to it:

```
var paragraphs = d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(text);
```

Then, using the entering selection, append the `<p>` elements to the body:

```
paragraphs.enter().append("p").text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Your DOM will now have:

```html
<body>
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <p>Third</p>
    <p>Fourth</p>
</body>
```

There's a lot that could definitely confuse you at this point, but I think this should give you a good start.

See also: [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: Thanks. This will help as it all sinks in.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some readings to get you started:

[Understanding selectAll, data, enter, append sequence](http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.ca/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html)
[Binding Data: Scott Murray D3 Tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/)

From the second link its explained:

> The answer lies with enter(), a truly magical method. Here’s our final code for this example, which I’ll explain:
>
> ```
> d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
>     .data(dataset)
>     .enter()
>     .append("p")
>     .text("New paragraph!");
> ```
>
> `.selectAll("p")` — Selects all paragraphs in the DOM. Since none exist yet, this returns an empty selection. Think of this empty selection as representing the paragraphs that will soon exist.

Basically, you are selecting DOM elements that do not exist yet and then appending data to these non-existent elements and then appending them after the data is bound.

Comment: Thanks. Both links are helpful; the first one (Understanding selectAll) helps illustrate what the `selectAll("Anything1")` does. I'd +1 but do not have enough reputation. I'll check back when I do.

Comment: Thanks - Wex wiped the floor with my answer ;) - Either way, glad you got it now.